# How get datetime from a property, changing default dateType in getter method?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, datetime, utc

Actually my sqldatabase with Entity Framework **save DateTime how date type local**, but i need in the class model **get that value ever like date type UTC**.
Exists one way from modify the getter method or a datanotation for change value type when i get it ?
I thought in :

```
 public class ClassDatetime
{
    public DateTime DateLocal { get { return DateLocal.ToUniversalTime(); } set { } }
}
```

But it's a error by stack overflow exception....

Comment: You code declares a property called `DateLocal`.  The code for the getter of that property is `return DateLocal.ToUniversalTime();`, This will call your  `DateLocal` property getter, which... will overflow your stack.  Do you really want to have a property named DateLocal for the UTC date/time?

Comment: Not, that code is only an example

Comment: Well, we can't help you fix your code if you don't show us your code.  The code you do show has a stack overflow in it.  Your property getter code references the property you are defining.  It will call itself forever and ever - until the stack overflows.  What do you really want to do, provide read only access to the UTC version of the local time.  If so, use something like `public DateTime DateUtc {get => DateLocal.ToUniversalTime();}`

Comment: Not is for fix, only is a dude, if is possible change the value from a property directly in getter method ?

Comment: You should not store local date and time. Save everything as UTC _or_ use `DateTimeOffset` _and_ a time zone identifier.